# Ionic 3 lazy loading with sub-page

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

I just started to refactor my app trying to use the Ionic 3 Lazy Loading.

For instance I have a page `EventPage` which now has a `EventPageModule`.

Everything works fine went navigating to it with a string reference.

But what I can't manage to do is to open a sub-page from this exact page.

Sub-page is `JoinersPage`...

JoinersPage:

```
// JoinersPage
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPage, NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@IonicPage()
@Component({
  selector: 'page-joiners',
  templateUrl: 'joiners.html',
})
export class JoinersPage {

  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams) {
  }

  ionViewDidLoad() {
    console.log('ionViewDidLoad JoinersPage');
  }

}
```

JoinersPageModule:

```
// JoinersPageModule
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { JoinersPage } from './joinersbis';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    JoinersPage,
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(JoinersPage),
  ],
})
export class JoinersPageModule {}
```

EventPageModule:

```
// EventPageModule
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { MomentModule } from 'angular2-moment';
import { IonicPageModule } from 'ionic-angular';
import { IonicImageLoader } from 'ionic-image-loader';

import { DirectivesModule } from '../../directives/directives.module';
import { PipesModule } from '../../pipes/pipes.module';

import { EventPage } from './event';
import { EventChatComponent } from './event-chat/event-chat.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    EventPage,
    EventChatComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    IonicPageModule.forChild(EventPage),
    IonicImageLoader.forRoot(),
    DirectivesModule,
    MomentModule,
    PipesModule
  ],
  entryComponents: []
})
export class EventPageModule {}
```

When I click the button that is supposed to open the `JoinersPage` with the following code `this.navCtrl.push('JoinersPage');`

I get the following error:

```
Error: No component factory found for JoinersPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
Error: No component factory found for JoinersPage. Did you add it to @NgModule.entryComponents?
```

1. I though that the all purpose of Ionic 3 Lazy Loading was to avoid importing the pages
2. How could I solve my issue ?

Comment: Can you please try to add "exports: [JoinersPage]," inside @NgModule decorator object in JoinersPageModule

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue

Comment: So strange... I just had to re-run `ionic serve`and it worked... have you ever experienced such behavior ? By the way, it worked without the need of the export statement

Comment: If you use lazy load, it absolutely does not need to export component. If you add a file yo your project, re-run is required.

Comment: For me its not working even adding exports to module.ts. I am using ionic CLI: 3.20.0, cli-utlils: 1.19.2, app-scripts:3.1.9. How to resolve this i am not able to get through